# Error on WP7 app WebRequest

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-7, webrequest

I have this errors on 'error List'.

```
'ContentLength' is not a member of 'System.Net.WebRequest'

'GetRequestStream' is not a member of 'System.Net.WebRequest'

'GetResponse' is not a member of 'System.Net.WebRequest'
```

I'm make an App WindowsPhone 7 with vb.net on VisualStudio 2010

i can't understand why. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public void SendPost(Uri uri, string json)
    {
    var webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
    webClient.UploadStringCompleted += this.sendPostCompleted;
    webClient.UploadStringAsync(uri, "POST", json);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't due to the async nature of WP. It seems like you have lifted examples from a non WP project. In WP, you have to make the call and then register an even that listens to the completion of the task. Further reading on [Async Calls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh221581.aspx)

```
private void GetSource(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Net.WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.bbc.co.uk");
        //request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = "GET";

        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), request);
    }

 private void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        var request = asynchronousResult.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;

        if (request != null)
        {
            try
            {
                WebResponse response = request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
                using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
                    {
                        var responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();

                        MessageBox.Show(responseString);
                    }                      
                }
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
               // Handle exception
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```